# UIAlertViewDelegate extended protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols, uialertview

I'm trying to extend the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol with one optional delegate method.

*interface*

```
@protocol HPAlertViewDelegate;

@interface HPAlertView : UIAlertView<UIWebViewDelegate>{
    id <HPAlertViewDelegate> delegate;
    UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <HPAlertViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;


- (id)initWithWebURL:(NSString *)url title:(NSString *)aTitle;

@end

@protocol HPAlertViewDelegate <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@optional
- (void)HPAlertViewWebViewDidLoad:(HPAlertView *)alertView;

@end
```

---

*implementation*

```
@dynamic delegate
```

when I use it in myViewController like:

```
HPAlertView *alertView = [[HPAlertView alloc] initWithWebURL:myURL tile:myTitle];
[alertView setDelegate:self];
```

I have 2 issues :

- if I set delegate to @dynamic, my delegate in HPAlertView is always null even with setDelegate:self
- if I set delegate to @synthesize, my delegate respond only to the new @optional delegate methods and not to UIAlertView delegate methods.

Comment: I know it's not what you are asking but you shouldn't really subclass `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `@synthesize` and then implement the setter as this:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id)aDelegate {
    super.delegate = aDelegate;
    delegate = aDelegate;
}
```

I guess `@synthesize` in your class will generate a new instance variables named `delegate` that is different from the super class `delegate` instance variable. You can read more about this here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html

Comment: Thanks but no, if I do that I will generate an infinite loop on setDelegate (self.delegate = [self setDelegate], so....)

Comment: nope, I was hable to make it works by -(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle delegate:(id<HPAlertViewDelegate>)aDelegate ...{
self = [super init...]
if (self){
super.delegate = aDelegate;
}
return self;
}